# clicking hyperlink multiple times , multiple tabs/windows should not open. only one window.tab should open

Tags: javascript, html, jsp-tags

In a `JSP` we are using display payment summary hyper link as follows:

```
<a href="javascript:window.print()">
<font size="2px">Print Summary</font></a>
```

Each time a User clicks on the hyperlink a new tab is opened with a suammary. We want to upgrade this functionality whenever a User clicks on hyperlink only one tab/window should be opened, not multiple.

How can i do this?

Comment: <a href="javascript:window.print()">
          <font size="2px">Print Summary</font></a>

Answer (score 0):

This is bad, and you should not do it. Don't break the web.

Nevertheless, you'd have to catch the click and add some logic to see if you should stop the event. Provided your markup looks like this:

```
<a href="blah.html" class="self-destructing">Don't you dare click me twice!</a>
```

You'd do something like:

```
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('a.self-destructing'), function(el){
    el.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        if (typeof e.target.dataset.visited !== 'undefined') {
            e.preventDefault();
        } else {
            e.target.setAttribute('data-visited', 1);
        }
    }, false);
});
```

Note that this only catches clicks, so if you activate the link with the keyboard or by some other means, the link will still be followed.

Comment: well i went for simple method

Comment: function openPaymentReceiptPopup() {    
  window.open("<%=basePath%>jsp/ordering/orderingReceiptPopup.jsp", "name");
  return false;
 }